# Not working in Chrome and Edge 'frames.filedownframe.location.href'

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge

exception is thrown for line `frames.filedownframe.location.href` in below piece of code which is in common.js and common.min.js file only in edge and Chrome, while its working fine in IE.

```
function fn_FileDownload(n) { var t = null; try { t = "/Common/AttachFileDownload.aspx?IDX=" + n; frames.filedownframe.location.href = t  } catch (i) { fn_OpenErrorMessage(i.description) } }
```

Comment: What error does it show in Edge and Chrome? What is `filedownframe`? The code you provide is not enough to reproduce the issue. Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue** so that we can have a test and see how to help?

Comment: Below is HTML & JS

HTML

<div id="divFileDownloadArea" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadListView ID="viewfileList" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="javascript:fn_FileDownload(<%#Eval("IDX")%>)" style="padding-left: 4px;"><span><%# Eval("DISPLAY_FILE_NAME") %></span></a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadListView>
</div>

Common.js

function fn_FileDownload(n) { var t = null; try { t = "/Common/AttachFileDownload.aspx?IDX=" + n;  frames.filedownframe.location.href = t  } catch (i) { fn_OpenErrorMessage(i.description) } }

Comment: Still can't tell what is `filedownframe` in your code. What is the detailed error message? Do you want to set the parent frame's src in child page? Could you please elaborate more about the structure of the frames nested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the following line of code:

```
frames.filedownframe.location.href = t
```

with this:

```
windows.location=t
```

I was able to download the attachment file.